# How does the Angular Router import Components of the ApplicationModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, module

In the Angular tutorial "Tour of Heroes" the following code is used to export certain components from the AppModule (AKA, the root of the app)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

A RouterModule is then used to route different URLs to different components. The router module looks like this:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The RouterModule is then added as an import for the AppModule. The RouteModule has a Typescript style import for the HeroesComponent, but it never imports it in the Angular style.

How does it know that it can route to this "component" if it hasn't imported it? Is there something else going on behind the scenes when the RouterModule is imported by the AppModule? I'm scared that since I don't understand this, I don't have a good grasp on Module behavior, and won't know how to correctly export/import components from modules in the future.